# Xfce4-panel default layout without asking a user (during the first login)

Tags: xfce, panel

I was browsing through the Internet and Xfce4 [Docs](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/getting-started) and couldn't find the answer. When a user log in for the first time, he/she is asked for the desired
panel layout. I would like to set "Default layout" for panels (in a multiuser system) without asking a user during the first login. Is there a system wide option to set this default?

New users are confused often when they see the popup and click "Cancel", which results in an empty screen with icons :) So, when a user login for the first time he/she should see the default panel layout and no question popup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a temporary user (eg `test`) and log in as that user. Configure `xfce-panel` as you would like it to be for all new users.

These settings should be in:

```
~/.config/xfce4/
```

Copy this whole tree to:

```
/etc/skel/
```

So that you have:

```
/etc/skel/.config/xfce4/
```

Now (hopefully) all your *new* users will have the same default `xfce4-panel` settings.

Answer (score 3):

Both answers so far advocate for putting default files below `/etc/skel`. That is a generic place only used to populate user's home directories *when they get created* using `useradd`.

But you might have existing users, or centralised users with NIS/NFS. If you want to change XFCE defaults for anyone who hasn't started it yet, put your files below `/etc/xdg`.

Answer (score 3):

see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1205840/1093368

> The defaults for the panel is stored in `/etc/xdg/xfce4/panel/default.xml`. So to restore that default, just do:

```
cp /etc/xdg/xfce4/panel/default.xml ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-panel.xml
```

I'm using ansible to prepare the user configuration with the following tasks:

```yml
  - name: Ensure directory for default panel configuration exists
    become: no
    ansible.builtin.file:
      path: ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml
      state: directory
      recurse: yes

  - name: Use default panel configuration
    become: no
    ansible.builtin.copy:
      src: /etc/xdg/xfce4/panel/default.xml
      dest: ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-panel.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach described here in this thread titled: [Setting up the default Panel layout](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1998125) seems like one way of doing this. You can do as described in this answer.

*excerpt*

> Ok, for anyone who would like to know this is how I was able to share
>   my xfce panel set-up.
>
> 1. Create a template account (lets call this user template) and set up the panels and launchers as you want them.
> 2. In the `/etc/skel` directory create a directory called `.config`:
>
>    ```
>    sudo mkdir /etc/skel/.config
>    ```
> 3. Into this directory copy the `.config/xfce` from the template account:
>
>    ```
>    sudo cp -r /home/template/.config/xfce /etc/skel/.config
>    ```
>
> Now when you log in as a new user they should see the panels and launchers 
>   that you set up as default.
>
> The question about the Places and the missing folders. From what I
>   understand when Thunar is run for the very first time it creates a
>   `.gtk-bookmarks` file in the format:
>
> ```
>     file:///home/<username>/Documents Documents
> ```
>
> To fix this so that a new user can immediately see the folders under Places I
>   do the following:
>
> 1. In `/etc/X11/Xsession.d` create a file called `95x11bookmarks`:
>
>    cd /etc/X11/Xsession.d gksu leafpad 95x11bookmarks
> 2. In this file add:
>
>    ```
>    if [ -f ~/.gtk-bookmarks ]; then
>        echo "" > /dev/null else
>        echo "file:///$HOME/Documents Documents" > ~/gtk-bookmarks
>        echo "file:///$HOME/Downloads Downloads" >> ~/gtk-bookmarks
>        echo "file:///$HOME/Music Music" >> ~/gtk-bookmarks
>        echo "file:///$HOME/Pictures Pictures" >> ~/gtk-bookmarks
>        echo "file:///$HOME/Videos Videos" >> ~/gtk-bookmarks 
>    fi
>    ```
>
> My understanding is that the files in `Xsession.d` are run when a user logs
>   in. If the user is new there will be no `.gtk-bookmarks`, so the above
>   script creates the file.